# PayPal Adaptive Payments, Chained payments, ngx-paypal

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, ngx-paypal

Currently PayPal Adaptive Payments marked as deprecated and do not have documentation for frontend. I cannot find any way how to achieve this with available documentation.

I'm writing an app on angular using ngx-paypal PayPal integration library. The app is a market where user can buy something from seller by paypal and I need to split this payment to take fee from it.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments is deprecated as you say. There are no generally available APIs to split fees off of a payment.

If you receive full amounts into your own account, you could later [send a Payout to another account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts), if you have access to that.